# Why is the module still inaccessible after installing the soup sieve?

Tags: terminal, beautifulsoup

I tried pip install soupsieve and succeeded, but the system still shows that no module is found.  [box on the right side is the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l09pt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple versions of Python installed? If so, You need to install it with the pip installed with the version of Python you are targeting.

Comment: Yeah I tried to pip install it in my specific version, but it still doesn't work:(